# In Azure DevOps Services where can one configure "Administer Permissions" access of a user to some Environment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-services

When I am trying to change the access of Project Administrators from Reader to Administrator I get

```
Access Denied: e...4 needs the following permission(s) on the resource Environments/f...6/7 to perform this action: Administer Permissions
```

Where `e...4` corresponds to the id of my user in Azure DevOps Services.
[image]

(I am a Project Administrator)

Who can grant these Administer Permissions rights? Is it some kind of Organization Administrator? Where its screen? Documentation? Rest API?

I could not find anything.

Comment: Check who created this environment and ask this person. Or check in the permissions section who has already administrator permission for this environment and ask him to set Administrator for that User Group.

Comment: There is only one administrator for this environment and this person no longer works here. I need to find the master screen or Rest API to be able to assign other people the Admin permissions. I am only Project Admin, maybe I need someone with higher permissions, like Org Admin. But I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: If you do not know who to ask directly there is always organization owner who should be able to provide you direction of just permissions, you can find this person in this section https://dev.azure.com/YOURORGANIZATIONNAME/_settings/organizationOverview

Comment: Suppose I know who he is. The question remains - where is the documentation? What screen? Is there REST API?

Comment: There is REST API document, but doesn't have specific API document for this, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the UI interface is improperly operated, even PCA (Project Collection Administrators) or Organization Owner will also be trapped in the UI interface here (the PCA/ORG Owner may also lose all operating permissions on Env in the UI interface of Env's permission settings.). But REST API can get rid of this situation.

There is a REST API document about this, but there doesn't have a specific document for this.

[Roleassignments - Set Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/securityroles/roleassignments/set-role-assignments?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

You can use f12 to capture the detailed request(UI also based on the above REST API).

I write a python demo to achieve your requirement.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.environmentreferencerole/roleassignments/resources/<Project ID>_<Env ID>?api-version=5.0-preview.1"

payload = json.dumps([
  {
    "userId": "<User ID>",
    "roleName": "Administrator"
  }
])
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic <Your Personal Access Token>',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Use [List Projects REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the project id.

Use [List Users REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the user ID.

Get the Env ID from the Env page url.